# How should I cite two different translations?

Tags: citation-style, translations

I want to cite in MLA style two different translations of *Alcestis* by Euripides. However, I’m mostly citing one the content of one translation, not “the translator’s comments or the choice of wording”, although I do that, too.

Here are the works in question:

- http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/10523
- http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0088

Answer (score 1):

Cite each translation where you use it, just as you would if they were different works.

To ease any confusion on the part of the reader, however, it would likely be a good idea to also:

1. In your introductory material, note that you are using two different translations and why your are doing so, and
2. Call attention in the prose when you use the unusual translation, and why you have chosen to use that one instead in this circumstance.

Comment: Do I use the same (Euripides line_no) parenthetical citation for either version?

Comment: No, you will need to distinguish the two, much the same as if you had two books by Euripides.